# Safari not sending "If-Modified-Since" and "If-None-Match" headers

Tags: php, safari, http-headers, etag, last-modified

I'm generating dynamic content with PHP.

I'm sending the following HTTP-header:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Sun, 09 Dec 2012 17:24:41 GMT
Server: Apache
Connection: keep-alive, Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=1, max=100
Etag: "237f43b800e655dbe6567f7d32d34c99"
Expires: Sun, 16 Dec 2012 17:24:41 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

I later check for the Etag to send a `header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified')` if it matches.
This works perfectly with Chrome and Firefox.
However, Safari (Version 6.0.2) does not send "If-Modified-Since" and "If-None-Match" headers. 
This is the Request-Header sent by Safari on the second page hit:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/536.26.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

All other files linked on that page receive the right Request-Headers and Safari used cached files or 304 where appropriate.

Why doesn't send Safari the correct Request-Header?
What could I change?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you forcing a refresh via f5/refresh button? Or loading the page more normally(submitting url field w/ enter key, or clicking a link)? I ask because it sent `Cache-Control: max-age=0`, which smells of a refresh.

Comment: Are these the headers for the actual page being requested listed in the nav bar or a linked page such as a resource within the page? It seems that Safari doesn't check the page cache if it's the page being requested in the nav bar, but if it's a resource within another page (ajax, js, css, img), it will check the cache first.

Comment: Those are indeeed the headers generated by a "reload" (CMD+r). However accessing the site by entering it's URL lets Safari generate the same Request-Header, just without the `Cache-Control`-Line. What I am irritated about is that Safari NEVER sends the Date or Etag in the Request-Header but Chrome and Firefox do.

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616015/how-to-make-safari-send-if-modified-since-header

Comment: The problem is too old by now to verify this but are you really sending these headers with a `304 Not Modified` response or is it just a copy & paste mistake and you are sending these headers in a `200 OK`?

Comment: @akirk – I can't check now anymore. But I remember to have tried Chrome and Firefox (as stated) which worked just fine.

Comment: @basbebe Your Expires header is 2 years in the past. Im not using safari, but I would not be suprised if they disregard all other caching header you send if that header explicitly state that the image should not be cached.

Comment: @Cleric the first thread is two years old – the date was seven days in the future back then.

Comment: @akirk resending these headers on a 304 response isn't bad practise, since clients have been known to 'forget' some otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### If-Modified-Since

The notes of [If-Modified-Since](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25) warn against using something different than the contents of the `Last-Modified` response header:

> Note: If a client uses an arbitrary date in the If-Modified-Since
>         header instead of a date taken from the Last-Modified header for
>         the same request, the client should be aware of the fact that this
>         date is interpreted in the server's understanding of time.

Your response doesn't contain a [Last-Modified](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29), but even if it did, nothing in the spec says that user agents MUST or SHOULD send If-Modified-Since, they just MAY.

#### If-None-Match

As to why Safari doesn't send an [If-None-Match](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.26) beats me; your [ETag](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.19) looks valid.

#### Enforcing Caching in general

Again in general nothing in the spec says you MUST cache, just that when you do, you MUST obey [Cache-Control](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9). So it's a bit of an asymmetric relation, you can enforce (transparent) caches to recheck with the origin server, but as an origin server, you can't enforce useragents to cache.

#### What can I do about it?

Safari is only [partly](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/releases/Apple/Safari%205.1/) free software. So nothing much, if adding a Last-Modified doesn't help.

Comment: I ran into the same issue concerning the If-Modified-Since header and was able to get Safari to provide it after initially returning both the Last-Modified header but also the Expires header with the same value. For more, I posted a solution on this related question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616015/how-to-make-safari-send-if-modified-since-header/26511701#26511701

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this one by looking for what headers are sent by various big sites, and have ended up with

```
Last-Modified: {some date}
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate
Expires: -1
```

This is working on Safari for me.

Comment: This works in 2020 and forces Safari to return HTTP 304 correctly.

Comment: I could not make this work for the initial page load (details in another answer).

Comment: That's weird @J

Answer (score 1):

Safari 16.3 (March 2023) never sends If-Modified-Since or If-None-Match for the initial document GET request initiated by the browser.

Compare the request and response headers between Safari and Chrome for example.com, which uses both ETags and Last-Modified.

#### Safari

When reloading example.com, Safari does not send the If-Modified-Since or If-None-Matches headers.

The server must return HTTP code 200 with all content since Safari does not include caching information in the request.

[image: Safari network request]

#### Chrome

When reloading example.com (don't reload too quickly--Chrome interprets rapid reloads as force-reload), Chrome sends both the If-Modified-Since and If-None-Match headers populated from the first load ETag and Last-Modified headers.

The server returns HTTP code 304 since the ETag hasn't changed.
[image: Chrome network request]

Comment: That's weird @Joe (and unfortunately not that surprising). Is that a documented change? 
I don't have a Mac to play with, but I wonder if it's odd behaviour with devtools enabled?
Sorry if I'm asking the obvious, but these things sometimes happen.

Comment: I had caching enabled for dev tools and I’m able to observe the behavior without dev tools open. I wasn’t able to find a bug report. There are many references to Safari’s behavior—looks like this behavior has been around since at least Safari 12: https://gertjans.home.xs4all.nl/javascript/cache-control.html

Comment: Thanks. It's surprising anything works!